# Standard for using the Me keyword in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, coding-style, standards, keyword

I'm looking to find out if there is a standard or preferred way for using the (Me) keyword in VB.Net syntax.

Currently I know of 3 ways to use (Me).

Without the (Me) keyword:

```
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

RadioButtonSortBySurname.Checked = True

LightGrid.SortColumn(2)
LightGrid.Columns(2).LastSortState = Ascending
LightGrid.SortColumn(1)
LightGrid.Columns(1).LastSortState = Ascending

Cursor = Cursors.Default

LightGrid.StatusRowText = ""
LightGrid.Select()
```

(Me) in a Using structure:

```
Using Me
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

    RadioButtonSortBySurname.Checked = True

    LightGrid.SortColumn(2)
    LightGrid.Columns(2).LastSortState = Ascending
    LightGrid.SortColumn(1)
    LightGrid.Columns(1).LastSortState = Ascending

    Cursor = Cursors.Default

    LightGrid.StatusRowText = ""
    LightGrid.Select()
End Using
```

Using (Me) on each control:

```
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

Me.RadioButtonSortBySurname.Checked = True

Me.LightGrid.SortColumn(2)
Me.LightGrid.Columns(2).LastSortState = Ascending
Me.LightGrid.SortColumn(1)
Me.LightGrid.Columns(1).LastSortState = Ascending

Cursor = Cursors.Default

Me.LightGrid.StatusRowText = ""
Me.LightGrid.Select()
```

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it's not a good fit for this site.  All of these options are valid and acceptable.  It is purely a matter of preference.  Personally I prefer the first option, but that's just me and I know other very good programmers will disagree.

Comment: Does the second example actually reference the ME?
You do not prefix the controls with a dot.

Answer (score 5):

There is one case where you *have* to use it, to help the compiler when the variable name is ambiguous:

```
Sub Foo(ByVal bar As Integer)
    Me.Bar = bar
End Sub
```

Which assigns a field in the class from an argument that has the same name.  Without `Me.` it assigns the argument value to itself, which compiles but is never what is intended.  Not so uncommon in vb.net since it is case insensitive.  Otherwise recommended, it can be painful to think of an argument identifier name that is different from the field name.  Some programmers (and tools) favor always giving the field name a leading underscore to avoid this problem.

But the ones you presented in your question are a matter of personal taste.  There are two benefits to prefixing `Me.`, it helps code readability since it indicates scope and narrows down where the reader has to look for the declaration.  And it really helps the IntelliSense popup narrow down the list of candidates, the feature I personally care about a great deal.  It is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I'll make sure I don't code it in a Using Me structure.

Answer (score 1):

The decision is only yours, all ways are acceptable, but... Some tools Like ReSharper recomends you to don't use the Me (VB) or this (C#) keyword to make your code more legible and smaller.

In my case I avoid using the Me keyword, but as I said, the decision is only yours.

Answer (score 0):

The ME is implied if you do not specifically use it. As Hans mentioned, sometimes you HAVE to use it because the scope of ME will be overridden by closer scoped names.

Like the others I only use it infrequently, usually when I cant remember what I called some control I just added two minutes ago... then I take it out again just because I don't care for the grammar LOL. I would have preferred "THIS" rather than ME.